# How to call a file from a different directory in a bash script

Tags: bash, grep, echo

I do not know how to properly word my bash script called "drinks" that requires calling from a file in a different directory to get the proper results.

If the syntax was correct like "drinks [NAME]" the output should be, by taking the output from another file,

($name) likes to drink:

(the results from grep -i ($name) [the file in another directory] | cut -f1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your **names** file looks like this:

> Alice:Amaretto
>   Bob:Bourbon
>   Chris:Campari

**drinks**:

```
#!/bin/bash

names="/path/to/names/file"
drink="$(grep -i ${1} ${names} | cut -d':' -f2)"
if [ "${drink}" == "" ]; then
  echo "${1} not found in ${names}."
else
  echo "${1} likes to drink ${drink}."
fi
```

**Output**:

```
$ ./drinks Alice
Alice likes to drink Amaretto.
$ ./drinks Bob
Bob likes to drink Bourbon.
$ ./drinks Dave
Dave not found in ./names
```